# Hack-free Wordpress custom post type image upload?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

How do you upload an image with a custom post type in Wordpress without hacking at core files or injecting that multipart thing with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on what you are going to use to *manage* those images once they are uploaded. If the upload-and-create-custom-post is all you care about, then you could do it with a trivial plugin.

However, if you want to do the whole management enchilada, then the simplest thing might be to *copy* the code in `wp-admin/upload.php` and `wp-admin/includes/template.php` and make your own changes to that. There are very few action/filter hooks in this code and some of the comments indicate that it goes way, *way* back. In `upload.php` there are several SQL statements that have `post_type='attachment'` hardwired. Changing those should be straightforward. Mercifully, you will probably have only a few changes to make in `template.php`. As the comment at the top of that file says, "A Big Mess. Also some neat functions that are nicely written." So true.

The one thing you must *not* do is hack the core files themselves. WP's one-click upgrade is critical to their security fixes.